# Safely accesing server-side only environment variable on SveletKit with Vite

Tags: environment-variables, vite, sveltekit

I have 2 environment variables on my SvelteKit app for my API endpoint, one is public API, one is internal API (accessing API directly via IP to bypass Cloudflare, etc.)

This is what I roughly want:

```
API_URL = runningInBrowser ? "https://example.com/api" : "https://101.101.101.101/api"
```

How can I safely put both of my environment variables and make sure that the internal API isn't exposed on client side / from SvelteKit's server-side renderer? I couldn't find a clear way to do it on Vite's doc.

What I'm planning to do is checking if the code is running on server side or not, if it's running on server side, access server side env variable using `dotenv` and `process.env`, otherwise use Vite's env variable. Is this method safe?

```js
import { browser } from "$app/env";

if (!browser) dotenv.config(); // load .env if on server-side
const API_URL = browser ? 
    import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL : // access exposed environment variable by Vite
    process.env.API_BASe_URL // access server side variable
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late, but there is a new way to manage environment variables.

There are 4 types:

- public
- private
- static
- dynamic

`private` variables are only for server side code, while `public` are meant to be used for client code.

`static` variables are to be used at build time, while `dynamic` ones are meant to be used dynamically.

They can be accessed like

```
import { env } from "$env/dynamic/public";
import { env } from "$env/static/public";
import { env } from "$env/dynamic/private";
import { env } from "$env/static/private";
```

Beware that the `private` modules can only be accessed server side.

See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private for more information